# Finding substrings inside strings inputted by the user

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to write down a substring finder that acts like the fowl language blockers in chats. For some reason the code crashes every time I run it.

```
int main ()
{
    char *sent;
    char *key1 = "WORD";
    printf("Input: \n");
    sent = scanf("%d");
    if(strstr(sent, key1) != NULL) {
        printf("YES");
    }
}
```

Comment: `sent = scanf("%d");` Where did you get this from? What makes you think it is right?

Answer (score 0):

You did not allocate memory for `sent`. When you write `char *sent`, the pointer is pointing to some uninitialized memory at an unknown address. When you read it in, it must have enough space to hold the input--scanf will not allocate memory for you. This is the revised code

```
int main()
{
    char sent[16];  /* alloced 16 chars, including '\0' */
    char *key1 = "WORD";

    printf("Input: \n");
    scanf("%s", sent);

    if (strstr(sent, key1) != NULL)
        printf("YES");

    return 0;
}
```

You also used `scanf` wrong. The `%d` specifier reads decimal integers, not strings. For a string, you will need `%s`. And `scanf` doesn't return the read value. It returns a failure/succeeded signal. you need to pass the address into the variable argument list.

A final note: If you are reading sentences, `scanf` will not suffice. You will need `fgets`:

```
char buf[80];
fgets(buf, 80, stdin);
```

`buf` will then contain the first 80 characters from the standard input.

Comment: Thank you! I can't upvote your post so I will just leave this.